# Кроссплатформенная верстка блока, проблема с отображением на iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, кроссбраузерность, кроссплатформенность

Имеется [сайт](http://partywell.ru) на wordpress, на котором в блоке выводится последний пост из рубрики. 
Проблема в том, что этот пост неправильно отображается на всех устройствах с iOS. Скриншоты ниже.

[image: Скриншот с десктопа]
[image: Android]
[image: iPhone 5s]

Задумано было как img в обертке, затем максимально упростил код до простого изображения, дошел уже до того, чтобы подгружать в :before - результат одинаков. Что я делаю не так?

Фрагмент кода:

```
<section data-scroll-index="6" id="section6" class="cd-section blog-section">
<h2 class="section-title">Блог</h2>
<?php // параметры по умолчанию
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'category_name'    => 'blog',
    );

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post) ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<style>
    #section6 .post:before {
        background-image:url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>)
    }
</style>
    <div class="post-content">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="full-link" target="_blank"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<div class="section-footer">
    <a href="/category/blog/" class="more-link">Больше статей <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел...суть в том, что я пропустил css-позиционирование, а именно - не указал `top:0` и `left:0` для `#post-`. На всех девайсах и браузерах, кроме iOS, по умолчанию принимался левый верхний край родительского блока, а на iOS - середина. Мир всем.